# Vue js, document.title type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string', Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

i want to do beforeenter with vue router but, I get this error

TS2322: Type 'string | symbol | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
17 |     beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
18 |       // console.log(to)
19 |       document.title = to.name
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
20 |       console.log(document.title)
21 |     }
22 |   }
```

i don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this because it should not be happen if you your route name is string

```
beforeEnter(to, from, next) 
{
      // console.log(to)
      
      if(typeof(to.name) === 'string'){
        document.title = to.name;
      }
      console.log(document.title)
  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that to.name is not defined. Try changing it like "test" or something. I don't know VueJS, so there may be something else causing it tho.